# Magento 2 : scope of knockout JS variable

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, scope

Here's my code -

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'jquery',
    'mage/url',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    $,
    urlBuilder,
    quote,
    checkoutData,
    selectShippingAddress
) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/shipping-address/list'
        },

        initObservable: function () {

        this._super()
            .observe({
                foo: ko.observable(false)                    
            });
        this._super()
            .observe({
                phoenix: ko.observable(false)                    
            });

        this.addresses = window.checkoutConfig.addresses;


        this.phoenix.subscribe(function(someVal){
            console.log("phoenix");
            var group = someVal;
            this.addresses.filter(function(el){
                console.log(el);
                return el.indexOf('Montreal');
            });
       this.foo.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);

        });


        return this;
        },



        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            return this;
        },


        getAddressGroups:function(){
            return window.checkoutConfig.addressGroups;
        }


    });
},


 );
```

> Error: TypeError: this.addresses is undefined

As far as I understand, `this.addresses` is a **global variable**.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a context issue as the context of `this` changes in Javascript, inside the below code:

```
this.phoenix.subscribe(function(someVal){
    console.log("phoenix");
    var group = someVal;
    this.addresses.filter(function(el){
        console.log(el);
        return el.indexOf('Montreal');
});
```

`this` does not have the same context as it does when you are setting it.

When you set it `this` is the component, and when you try and access it `this` looks to be the event from the subscribe event (check by adding `console.log(this)` inside your subscribe function.

You can solve it by storing the 'correct' context in a variable. Outside your subscribe function add `var self = this;` and then use `self` instead of `this` - `self.addresses.filter(function(el)`.

I recommending reading about `this` in Javascript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

The working code would be:

```
var self = this;

this.phoenix.subscribe(function () {
    self.addresses.filter(function (el) {
        console.log(el);
        return el.indexOf('Montreal');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I am getting an error - self.addresses.filter is not a function. Is there some way that I can assign the return value of this.phoenix.subscribe to this.addresses?

Comment: What does `console.log(window.checkoutConfig.addresses);` return? It sounds like it is not an array which is why filter is not an array. The subscribe function isn't returning anything so I'm unsure what you need to do sorry.

Comment: window.checkoutConfig.address returns array `[{
   "optionLabel":"Hello1",
   "optionValue":"1"
},
{
   "optionLabel":"Hello2",
   "optionValue":"2"
},
{
   "optionLabel":"Hello3",
   "optionValue":"3"
},
{
   "optionLabel":"Hello4",
   "optionValue":"4"
}]`.
Here's what I need - I have two dropdowns. When the value of one changes, the options in the other one should update. Thanks